# On-again, off-again time series

Tags: time-series, optimization

I have a simple problem but don't know how to search for its solutions in the literature.  What keywords do you associate with this?:

A man walks into a bar.  He stays a while.  He leaves.  Hours later, he enters the bar again.  He stays a while.  He leaves. .... [there is no punchline].  In general, the duration of each visit and the time between visits is only semi-regular. The man is the bar's sole client.

The bar owner wants to replace the bar tender with a robot, but he's not very good at robotics.  The best he can do is make a robot that serves a drink every t hours, starting from some time $t_0$.  If the bar's sole client happens to be there when the robot serves the drink, the bar owner earns C dollars*.  Otherwise, the bar owner loses D dollars. Given historical data on the bar's sole client entering and leaving the bar, how should the bar tender choose $t_0$ and $t$ in a way that maximizes his expected future earnings?

*Caveat:  The client is totally smashed after a single drink, and will refuse any further drinks offered to him in the course of the same visit. Thus, the bar owner loses D dollars whenever the robot serves a second drink within the same visit.

In the general case $C$ and $D$ can be different, but even a solution that assumes $C = D$ (or one that only notionally maximizes profit) could be of interest.

Comment: If you view this as a question of how to forecast the customer's future behavior, it's too broad.  If instead you find $(t_0, t)$ to maximize *past* earnings in the expectation this will work well for the future (which is reasonable, requires few assumptions, and can be checked), then the problem of finding optimal $(t_0, t)$ given any $(C,D)$ looks straightforward.

Comment: A solution that optimizes $(t_0, t)$ for the past would be a great start.  So maybe this is more of a mathematical optimization problem than a stats question?

Comment: What happens when the robot serves more than one drink while the customer is in the bar?

Comment: @whuber, I forgot to say that!  See updates.

Comment: Perhaps this problem could be usefully modeled using a generalization of [Poisson processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process). For example, the client's entrance times might be Poisson-distributed and his exit times might be uniformly distributed between the two adjacent entrance times. An even simpler model would use just a Poisson process where the events are alternating entrances and exits.

Comment: By "semi-regular" is sounds like you mean there is a probability density function that describes the customer's visits, given a period of time.  The owner needs to learn that PDF as a function of time, and that is what temporal difference learning algorithms in reinforcement learning are quite good at. Check out Sutton & Barto's Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction for basic insight.  I can try to create an answer example if you think this makes sense for your problem.